# how to add scrolllayout in the framelayout from maya python

Tags: python, maya

I have a frameLayout to load the images, if i load more images i am unable to see all the images, 
for this reason i need to add the scrollLayout in the frameLayout, so that i can scroll and see the images.
Here i am unable to add the scrollLayout within the frameLayout.

Here my code...

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import re,sys,os
class assetBrowseTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if (cmds.window('assetBrowseWindow', q=True, ex=True)):
            cmds.deleteUI('assetBrowseWindow')
        assetWindow = cmds.window('assetBrowseWindow', title="xxxxxxx V1.0",s = False,widthHeight=(930, 530) )
        form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=100, width=215, height=175)
        frame = cmds.frameLayout('imageFrame', label='Assets', borderStyle='in',w = 200, h = 200 )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
        cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=[
        (tabs, 'top', 450), (tabs, 'left', 720), (tabs, 'bottom', 5), (tabs, 'right', 5),
        (tabs, 'right', 0),
        (frame,'left',5),(frame,'top',70),(frame,'bottom',5),(frame,'right',210)])
        child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfRows=1)
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1)
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        child3 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1)
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'IMPORT'), (child2, 'PUBLISH'),(child3, 'EXPORT')) )
        cmds.showWindow( 'assetBrowseWindow' )

assetBrowseTool()
```

## for scrollLayout

```
scrollLayout = cmds.scrollLayout(horizontalScrollBarThickness=0, verticalScrollBarThickness=0 )        
value = cmds.scrollLayout(scrollLayout, query=True, scrollAreaValue=True)
top = value[0]
left = value[1]
```

How to add scrollLayout code into the above window.
Thanks.

Comment: You want scrollLayout hold your all other widgets or you want to add scrollLayout to specific widget like frameLayout ?

Comment: only frameLayout is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct then you want a scrolLayout inside the frameLayout, If that the case then here s working eg, which is a slight modification from your code.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import re,sys,os
class assetBrowseTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if (cmds.window('assetBrowseWindow', q=True, ex=True)):
            cmds.deleteUI('assetBrowseWindow')
        assetWindow = cmds.window('assetBrowseWindow', title="xxxxxxx V1.0",s = False,widthHeight=(930, 530) )
        form = cmds.formLayout(numberOfDivisions=100, width=215, height=175) 
        frame = cmds.frameLayout('imageFrame', label='Assets', borderStyle='in',w = 500, h = 500 )
        scrollLay = cmds.scrollLayout("blaaa", horizontalScrollBarThickness=0, verticalScrollBarThickness=0, p =frame )  
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.setParent( '..' )    
        tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=5, innerMarginHeight=5)
        cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=[
        (tabs, 'top', 450), (tabs, 'left', 720), (tabs, 'bottom', 5), (tabs, 'right', 5),
        (tabs, 'right', 0),
        (frame,'left',5),(frame,'top',70),(frame,'bottom',5),(frame,'right',210)])
        child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfRows=1)
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.iconTextButton(l = '',w = 60,h = 40,style='iconOnly')
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1)
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        child3 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1)
        cmds.setParent( '..' )
        cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'IMPORT'), (child2, 'PUBLISH'),(child3, 'EXPORT')) )
        cmds.showWindow( 'assetBrowseWindow' )

assetBrowseTool()
```